# Duda acerca consultas en MySql y pasar datos en laravel a una view

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

tengo una duda sobre la consulta de tablas en Mysql, quiero obtener datos diferentes sobre una encuesta y despues sumar estos datos.

Tengo entendido que tengo que llamar mis datos de las 3 tablas asi

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
FROM ((Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID);
```

Llego a comprender un poco la sintaxis de esto pero en laravel no se como podria aplicarlo en la parte del controlador.

y basicamente es obtener datos de una encuesta, los valores que obtengo son numeros estos mismos numeros al obtenerlos los sumare y el total se guardara en una variable, pero ahora me preocupa mas como obtener los datos. Estas son mis tablas.

Mi tabla Usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla Preguntas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla de Respuestas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente a la complicación que nada mas no me da la lógica es como voy a cachar estos resultados y mostrarlos por usuario, espero me puedan a ayudar a orientarme un poco en esto, uso **Laravel 5.5** **PHP 7.0** **Mysql**

Agrego las relaciones conforme las tengo en mi proyecto de laravel

Usuario:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    //use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'usuario';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_usu';

    protected $fillable = ['nombre','email'];

    // protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

     public function usuario()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Encuesta');
     }
}
```

Respuestas:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Respuestas extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'respuestas';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_respuestas';    

    protected $filleable = [

        'respuesta1',
        'respuesta2',
        'respuesta3',
        'respuesta4',
        'respuesta5',
        'id_preguntas'
    ];

    public function encuesta()
    {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Encuesta');

    }
}
```

Preguntas:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Encuesta extends Model
{
    protected $table = "preguntas";

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_preguntas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'preguntas',
        'id_usu',

    ];
    public function usuarios()
    {

    return $this->belonsTo('App\Usuario');

    }

    public function respuestas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Respuestas');
    }
}
```

E echo la consulta con Laravel como Oswuell la posteo y en efecto me da estos datos

Codigo:

```
$s1 = DB::table('preguntas as p','')
        ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
            $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
        })
        ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
            $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
        })
        ->select('p.id_preguntas','p.preguntas','r.id_respuestas','r.respuesta1','r.respuesta2','r.respuesta3','r.respuesta4','r.respuesta5')
        ->get();

        return $s1;
```

Resultado:

```
[{"id_preguntas":1,"preguntas":"A","id_respuestas":1,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"1","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"3"},{"id_preguntas":2,"preguntas":"B","id_respuestas":2,"respuesta1":"3","respuesta2":"2","respuesta3":"5","respuesta4":"1","respuesta5":"4"},{"id_preguntas":3,"preguntas":"C","id_respuestas":3,"respuesta1":"1","respuesta2":"2","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"4","respuesta5":"5"},{"id_preguntas":4,"preguntas":"D","id_respuestas":4,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":5,"preguntas":"E","id_respuestas":5,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":6,"preguntas":"F","id_respuestas":6,"respuesta1":"1","respuesta2":"2","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"4","respuesta5":"5"},{"id_preguntas":7,"preguntas":"G","id_respuestas":7,"respuesta1":"4","respuesta2":"5","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"1","respuesta5":"2"},{"id_preguntas":8,"preguntas":"H","id_respuestas":8,"respuesta1":"2","respuesta2":"3","respuesta3":"1","respuesta4":"4","respuesta5":"5"},{"id_preguntas":9,"preguntas":"I","id_respuestas":9,"respuesta1":"3","respuesta2":"5","respuesta3":"4","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":10,"preguntas":"J","id_respuestas":10,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":11,"preguntas":"K","id_respuestas":11,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":12,"preguntas":"L","id_respuestas":12,"respuesta1":"2","respuesta2":"3","respuesta3":"1","respuesta4":"5","respuesta5":"4"},{"id_preguntas":13,"preguntas":"M","id_respuestas":13,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":14,"preguntas":"N","id_respuestas":14,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":15,"preguntas":"O","id_respuestas":15,"respuesta1":"2","respuesta2":"1","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"4","respuesta5":"5"},{"id_preguntas":16,"preguntas":"P","id_respuestas":16,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"2","respuesta3":"1","respuesta4":"4","respuesta5":"3"},{"id_preguntas":17,"preguntas":"Q","id_respuestas":17,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"4","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"2","respuesta5":"1"},{"id_preguntas":18,"preguntas":"R","id_respuestas":18,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"2","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"1","respuesta5":"4"},{"id_preguntas":19,"preguntas":"R","id_respuestas":19,"respuesta1":"5","respuesta2":"2","respuesta3":"3","respuesta4":"1","respuesta5":"4"}]
```

Lo que vendria siendo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la cuestion es saber filtrar un mas los resultados y sumar lo que respondio el usuaio (id_usu)

Edit:

```
$s1 = DB::table('preguntas as p')
        ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
            $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
        })
        ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
            $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
        })
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(respuesta1) as s1'))
        ->where('u.id_usu','=',"1")
        ->whereIn('p.preguntas',['A','G','M'])
        ->get();
        //respuesta 2

        $s2 = DB::table('preguntas as p')
        ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
            $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
        })
        ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
            $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
        })

        ->where('u.id_usu','=',"1")
        ->whereIn('p.preguntas',['A','G','M'])
       // ->where('p.preguntas','=','A')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(respuesta2) as s2')) 
        ->get();    

$s3 = DB::table('preguntas as p')
    ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
        $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
    })
    ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
        $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
    })

    ->where('u.id_usu','=',"1")
    ->whereIn('p.preguntas',['C','I','O'])
   // ->where('p.preguntas','=','A')
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(respuesta5) as s3')) 
    ->get();   


    return $s1.$s2.$s3;
```

dando resultado:

```
[{"s1":15}][{"s2":12}][{"s3":5}]
```

Comment: ¿Te funciona la consulta que haces?

Comment: Sería bueno también que coloques como están configuradas las relaciones en Laravel y dependiendo de eso ver el query que se pueda hacer para que obtengas los datos deseados

Comment: @Oswuell la ejecute acomodando los paremetros como lo tengo en mis tablas y me arroja 0, tal vez hice algo mal.

SELECT preguntas.id_preguntas, respuestas.id_respuestas, usuario.id_usu FROM ((preguntas INNER JOIN respuestas ON preguntas.preguntas = respuestas.id_preguntas) INNER JOIN usuario ON preguntas.id_usu = usuario.id_usu)

Comment: @HCK Listo las he agregado

Comment: Tienes que hacer 2 inner join

Comment: claro la complicacion aqui es que me tiene que regresar son 3 datos, por ejemplo en mi `Tabla Preguntas` me da el campo A,G,M con el campo de mi `Tabla preguntas ` el campo respuesta 1, **No se si sea posible** hacer otro inner join para que saque esos resultados de lo que contesto el usuaio `Èjmplo id_usu = 1` para despues esos valores obtenido sumarlos y enviarlos a una view de resultados

Comment: Pero aqui la cosa se me complico ya que no se como decirle a laravel que imprima esos resultados con lo que respondio cada usuario y los arroje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

Primera consulta te trae todos las preguntas

```
SELECT p.id_preguntas, p.preguntas, r.id_respuestas, r.respuesta1, r.respuesta2, r.respuesta3, r.respuesta4, r.respuesta5, u.id_usu, u.nombre, u.email FROM preguntas AS p INNER JOIN respuestas AS r ON p.id_preguntas = r.id_preguntas INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON p.id_usu = u.id_usu
```

Segunda consulta te trae todas las preguntas por usuario

```
SELECT p.id_preguntas, p.preguntas, r.id_respuestas, r.respuesta1, r.respuesta2, r.respuesta3, r.respuesta4, r.respuesta5, u.id_usu, u.nombre, u.email FROM preguntas AS p INNER JOIN respuestas AS r ON p.id_preguntas = r.id_preguntas INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON p.id_usu = u.id_usu WHERE u.id_usu = '".$id."'
```

Comment: La primera consulta funciono bien, la segunda me arrojo 0 rows, habra una manera de hacer otro inner join en la primera consulta que tambien traiga el campo de preguntas?

Comment: En la segunda consulta tienes que pasarle el ID del usuario para que te liste las preguntas de ese usuario.

Comment: Muy bien definire en la consulta que traiga el `ID` y lo mostrare en un `return` realizare pruebas

Comment: Perfecto. Si te sirve no olvides aceptar la respuesta para ayudar a otros de la comunidad.

Comment: gracias oswuell solo tuve que insertar ese otro join debajo de la consulta y tomo los datos que requeria

Answer (score 2):

Me está costando entender que es exactamente lo que necesitas.  Además tampoco entiendo para que definís las relaciones en los Modelos o incluso para que generás los modelos si no los usás.
Segun lo que entiendo necesitas sumar los resultados de las respuestas de cada pregunta de cada usuario. Si ese es el caso podrías intentar algo como:

1- renombrá el nombre del metodo en el modelo Usuario. En lugar que que se llame `usuario()` debería llamarse `encuestas()`.

2- en el Modelo `Encuesta` creo que la relación `respuestas()` debería ser singular y una relación de `hasOne` ya que una pregunta deberia tener solo una respuesta (esto me lo dice la logica quizá no sea el caso, vos me dirás si estoy equivocada). Quedaría así:

```
public function respuesta()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Respuestas');
}
```

3- Entonces hora obtemos el resultado de cada pregunta que si entendí bien consiste en la sumatoria de las 5 respuestas (respuesta1 + respuesta2 + respuesta3 + respuesta4 + respuesta5)

```
// Selecciono el usuario del que quiero obtener los resultados
$usuario = Usuario::find($id_usuario);

$resultados = collect();

// Por cada pregunta del usuario sumo las respuestas
foreach($usuario->encuestas as $encuesta) {
    $encuesta->resultado = array_sum(array_only($encuesta->respuesta, ['respuesta1', 'respuesta2', 'respuesta3', 'respuesta4', 'respuesta5']));
    $resultados->push($encuesta);
}

return view('VIEW_NAME')->with('encuestas_con_resultados', $resultados);
```

Espero haber entendido bien lo que estás necesitando y que este codigo (obviamente sin testear) te oriente un poco en el camino a la solución de tu problema y además en como utilizar las relaciones en Laravel.

Comment: Hola Maru gracias por brindarme tu ayuda primero que nada tal vez en la relacion si esta mal ya que por ejemplo en la tabla `respuestas` se guarda asi ` tabla Pregunta = A` y sus respectivas respuestas `1,2,3,4,5 (respuesta1,respuesta2...respuesta5` y asi hasta la letra _r_, y por ultimo si, sumo las respuestas pero en si que bueno que me provees de como hacer la suma porque hare algo distinto con la suma de estas, sumare de la ` tabla preguntas campo A,G,M` y solo sumare la `respuesta1` y la guardare, lo mismo con los campos de `respuesta 2` y así sucesivamente hasta sumar las `respuestas 5`

Comment: La verdad que me está costando entender la estructura de tu encuesta y por eso no puedo ser de mas ayuda. Si las preguntas son siempre las mismas quizá ni te conviene una estructura tan grande y podes manejar todo en una misma tabla y manejar las respuestas en una columna de tipo json. Algo como: `encuesta` [user_id, respuestas] y en respuestas tendrias un json o un array [{preguntaA: 1,2,3,4,5...}, {preguntaB: 1,2,3,4,5...}, {preguntaC: 1,2,3,4,5...}] y de esta forma incluso podes sumar mucho mas facil y con un codigo mucho mas optimizado

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices y eso lo intente pero lo que necesito sumar no es como tal todo lo de la pregunta A o B, si no es sumar por ejemplo [{preguntaA:1}] [{preguntaB:1}][{preguntaC:1}], ahora esto ya lo tengo con el WhereIn  y el Raw pude sumar una parte y quedo asi [{"s1":15}][{"s2":10}][{"s2":12}], ahora necesito sumar estos 3 arrays, edito la pregunta para que veas mejor lo que logre